# unable to display fetched data on page, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

*here my code i am fecthing data from api and want to display it on the page*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import '../all.css';
import Axios from "axios";


const AllProduct = () => {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

const fetchProducts = async () => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(
     "http://localhost:8080/api/QueryAllProducts"

    );
    
  const products = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  setProducts(products);
  console.log(products);
};
const display = () => {
  return products.map(product => (
    <tr>
       <th>{product.id}</th>
       <th>{product.name}</th>
       <th>{product.area}</th>
       <th>{product.ownerName}</th>
       <th>{product.cost}</th>
     </tr>
   ) );
  
 }
useEffect(() => {
  fetchProducts();
}, []);

  return (
    
    <div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Owner Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  {display}
 
</table>
    </div>
  
  
  )
}

export default AllProduct;
```

**But i am not able to display it on page. In frontend i have used ReactJS and in backend i hvae used nodeJS, Hyperledger Fabric and CouchDB database **

[here i am attaching one screenshot that i am geeting output in console but i don't able to display it on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz7ZX.png)

Comment: The response is an array of objects, not a single object. You can’t just ignore an entire layer of your data structure.

Comment: is there any way we can display it on page?

Comment: Yeah. Just don't completely ignore the fact you have an array.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the response is in json string, either fix the backend to return an actual array/object to your liking or just parse the output like:

```
  const products = JSON.parse(data);
```

And ofcourse since its an array you can't just display it like that, wrap it in a loop:

```
const display = () => {
 return products.map(product => (
   <tr>
      <th>{product.id}</th>
      <th>{product.name}</th>
      <th>{product.area}</th>
      <th>{product.ownerName}</th>
      <th>{product.cost}</th>
    </tr>
 );
}
```

then call `display` inside the element

Comment: i did but still same problem

Comment: i have updated the question can you please check it again and tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score -1):

As I can see from the screenshot at line 92 you are printing the products.
So, see it is a JSON string, not the object.
For that, you will need to parse this JSON and then set it in your state.

do something like this.

`setProducts(JSON.parse(data));`